# Computing word probabilities under topics and under documents in R with topic models package

Tags: r, matrix, text-mining, tm, topic-modeling

Griffiths and Steyvers give an example of word probabilities under topics in their 2006 book contribution.

I'm using R and would like to reproduce such word probabilities per topic and per document applied to my own data. Unfortunately, I'm pretty new to R and topicmodels and I grow desperate since the answer to that particular question seems to be so obvious that nobody asks the question.

So, given a DTM or a TDM or the results of the `LDA` function in [`topicmodels`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/index.html) package, how can I get the posterior distribution?

The following output like in Griffiths and Steyvers would be great:

Topic xyz

word prob.
hello       0.069
world       (1-0.069)

In the paper, they give this kind of output for several topics - this short one is just for clarifying my question.

PS: Any links or hints would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you use `?LDA` and try the examples?

Comment: Just did it. Solved one problem by giving the topic probabilities per document. Still, cannot retrieve the word probabilities per doc or topic. Maybe I don't see wood for the trees?

Comment: I think you want `topicmodels::posterior(lda_model)[["terms"]]
`